# Why is my BorderLayout not working with my JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border-layout, flowlayout

When I put in my JPanel to work with a BorderLayout, it tells me: `constructer JPanel in class JPanel cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments;
found: BorderLayout;
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length;`

Here is my code:

```
public class MTGSAMPServerReference extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); 
    static int ScrnWidth = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
    static int ScrnHeight = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static JList list1;
    private static JButton next;

    public MTGSAMPServerReference() {
        // set flow layout for the frame
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        Object[] data1 = { "Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3", "Value 4", "Value 5" };
        JPanel controls = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(5,5) ); // The line getting the main error.
        list1 = new JList<Object>(data1);
        list1.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        next = new JButton("Next");
        next.addActionListener(this);
        controls.add(new JScrollPane(list1)); // A result error of the JPanel error ^
        controls.add(next, BorderLayout.PAGE_END); // A result error of the JPanel error ^
        // adjust numbers as needed.
        controls.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(25,25,0,0));

        add(controls); // A result error of the JPanel error ^
        // add list to frame
        add(list1);
        add(next);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Next")) {
            int index = list1.getSelectedIndex();
            System.out.println("Index Selected: " + index);
            String s = (String) list1.getSelectedValue();
            System.out.println("Value Selected: " + s);
        }
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame f = new MTGSAMPServerReference();
        //Display the window.
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.setSize(1200, 800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        list1.setSize(250, 250);
        list1.setLocation(0, 0);
        next.setSize(75, 25);
        next.setLocation(251, 276);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
        }
        });
    }
}
```

What is missing in my code?
I have all of my imports, and I am sure it is just a minor error, perhaps a typo.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here are the imports I have:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
```

Comment: Why do you leave out the `import` statements?

Comment: @AndrewThompson People are always telling me to put in only the necessary code. And I have been told in the past not to include imports. Should I include them?

Comment: *"Should I?"*  I would put 'package imports' into an SSCCE, like I did with the example I provided for you.  It adds only 5 lines (in this case) to the source code, and makes it quite clear what packages contain the classes.  As an aside, when I **do** add the imports seen in the SSCCE - that code compiles for me, without any warnings or errors.

Comment: Do you name shadow JPanel somewhere in your code?  JPanel does in fact have a constructor that takes a LayoutManager.

Comment: You didn't redefine your own `JPanel` class somewhere, did you? If you fully-qualify it, does the issue go away? `javax.swing.JPanel controls  = new javax.swing.JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));`

Comment: @damo Wow, I didn't even realize it, but I accidently clicked something a while back and created a file `JPanel` so everything was looking there... I am so sorry for wasting your guys's time!

Comment: *"I am so sorry for wasting your guys's time!"*   We'll get over it.  ;)  The best thing to do now (or when the site allows) is to either a) delete the question using the links below the question tags.. ***or*** b) wait a while and enter your own answer.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Comment: @onepotato Why would anyone delete this thread? This thread has been solved. There is absolutely NO REASON for it to be deleted. Marked as non constructive.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have not created any files with reserved words or class names.